# Matplotlib scatterplot, color as function of element in array

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I'm trying to plot data with different colors depending on their classification. The data is in an nx3 array, with the first column the x position, the second column the y position, and the third column an integer defining their categorical value. I can do this by running a for loop over the entire array and plotting each point individually, but I have found that doing so massively slows down everything.

So, this works.

```
data = np.loadtxt('data.csv', delimiter = ",")
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b']

fig = plt.figure():
for i in data:
plt.scatter(i[0], i[1], color = colors[int(i[2] % 3]))
plt.show()
```

This does not work, but I want it to, as something along this line would avoid using a for loop.

```
data = np.loadtxt('data.csv', delimiter = ",")
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b']

fig = plt.figure():
plt.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], color = colors[int(data[:,2]) % 3])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because your `x` and `y` values are arrays from the data while color is not. So, you have to define it as an array. Just a look at the matplotlib page:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/shapes_and_collections/scatter.html They have this example there:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

N = 50
x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)
colors = np.random.rand(N)
area = (30 * np.random.rand(N))**2  # 0 to 15 point radii

plt.scatter(x, y, s=area, c=colors, alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Here, you have the same `x` and `y`. Probably, you won't need `s`. `Color` is an array. You can do something as follows:

```
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b']
colors_list = [colors[int(i) % 3] for i in data[:,2]]
plt.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], c = colors_list)
```

Just note that since I don't have the data to test it, you may need to tweak the code just in case.

Comment: Thank you. The solution you provided where I create a separate array for colors and plot from that works well enough.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your array it's hard to know exactly what your data look like (my answer doesn't have a %3, but that's easy enough to insert depending on what data[:,2] looks like). This has a for loop, but only loops 3 times so will be fast.

```
for ind,col in enumerate(colors):
    plt.scatter(data[:,0][data[:,2]==ind], data[:,1][data[:,2]==ind], c = col)
```